# Creating groups containing slopes of a specific range

Tags: qgis, slope

I have a basic knowledge of QGIS and can do everything I need to do to achieve my requirements except the following.

I'm trying to graphically show areas of land that contain a set of specific slope ranges.

I'm working in relatively small areas of up to 50ha.

I have the DEM and can create contours with no problem.

What im trying to do is shown in the attached image, I know it can be done but I just don't know how to do it or what the process is called.

[image]

Comment: have you calculated the slope?

Comment: Only manually over certain runs which seems to be adaquate for my current needs. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Terrain analysis](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/terrain_analysis.html) to generate slopes from your DEM. Then you can add a thematic display to the slope layer.